# Is String.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf16) working correctly?

Tags: swift, string, utf-16

I'm seeing strange behavior w/ string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf16).
What I'm trying to do is to convert Swift String to utf-16 in UnsafePointer<'UInt16>. However, String.Encoding.utf16 seems to terminate conversion after it outputs first '\0'.
The same logic works for utf-8 or shiftJIS, since they don't have NULL byte on the way.

Here is the code.

```
func test() {
  let str = "helloはろー"
  let cnt = str.characters.count
  // (A) utf-8 ==> works fine
  let utf8 = str.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
  let int8p = utf8.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    UnsafeRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self)
  }
  dumpmem(0, int8p)
  let str1 = String(cString: int8p)
  print(str1)  // helloはろー
  // (B) shift-JIS ==> works fine
  let sjis = str.cString(using: String.Encoding.shiftJIS)!
  let uint8p = sjis.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    UnsafeRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
  }
  dumpmem(0, uint8p)
  let str2 = String(sjisptr: uint8p)!
  print(str2)  // helloはろー
  // (C) utf-16 ==> doesn't work nicely
  let utf16 = str.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf16)!
  let uint16p = utf16.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    UnsafeRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self)
  }
  dumpmem(Int32(str.characters.count*2), uint16p)  // only top char (='h' converted)
  let str3 = String(utf16ptr: uint16p)!
  print(str3)  // h+garbage ...
  // (D) utf-16 w/ iteration ==> works fine.
  let u16s = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.allocate(capacity: cnt*4)
  var len = 0
  for code in str.utf16 {
    u16s[len] = code
    len += 1
  }
  u16s[len] = 0
  dumpmem(Int32(len*2), u16s)
  let str4 = String(utf16ptr: u16s)!
  u16s.deallocate(capacity: cnt*4)
  print(str4)  // helloはろー
}
```

and support functions follow.

```
// dump memory
void dumpmem(int len, const void *ptr) {
  unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)ptr;
  if (!len)  len = (int)strlen((char *)p);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    printf("[%d] : %d : 0x%x", i, *p, *p);
    if (isascii(*p))  printf(" : %c", *p);
    printf("\n");
    p++;
  }
}
// create string from Shift JIS pointer=UInt8
extension String {
  init?(sjisptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) {
    var len = 0
    while (sjisptr[len] != 0) {
      len += 1
    }
    let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(sjisptr), count: len)
    if let ns = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.shiftJIS.rawValue) {
      self = ns as String
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
// create string from UTF-16 pointer=UInt16
extension String {
  init?(utf16ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) {
    var len = 0
    while (utf16ptr[len] != 0) {
      len += 1
    }
    len += len
    let data = Data(bytes: utf16ptr, count: len)
    if let ns = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf16LittleEndian.rawValue) {
      self = ns as String
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Since utf-16 conversion doesn't work nicely w/ cString(using: String.Encoding.utf16) (C), I ended up iterating (scan) string as shown in (D) above.

I may be missing something. Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is String.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf16) working correctly?***

The answer is NO.

The word "CString" means NUL terminated byte sequence. And NUL always means a single byte 0x00 in CString.

As you know, UTF-16 representation may contain many 0x00 bytes, such encodings cannot be used as CString.

And other points to fix your code:

- You should not take out the bufferPointer or its `baseAddress` out of the closure passed to `withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`.

[withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1540400-withunsafebufferpointer)

> ### Parameters
>
> **body**
>
> A closure with an UnsafeBufferPointer parameter that points to the
>   contiguous storage for the array. If body has a return value, it is
>   used as the return value for the withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:) method.
>   **The pointer argument is valid only for the duration of the closure’s execution.**

And in many cases, you have no need to use `withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`.

- To get the size of UTF-16 representation, you should use `str.utf16.count`, not `str.characters.count`.
- Swift3's `String` has an initializer `init(cString:encoding:)` method. You have no need to re-implement it.
- `len += len` is sort of "unreadable". Use `len * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size` or at least `len * 2`.

Try this code:

```
// dump memory written in Swift
func dumpmem(_ len: Int, _ ptr: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    var p = ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    let len = len == 0 ? Int(strlen(ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))) : len
    for i in 0..<len {
        print(String(format: "[%d] : %2$d : 0x%2$x", i, p.pointee), terminator: "")
        if isascii(Int32(p.pointee)) != 0 {print(String(format: " : %c", p.pointee), terminator: "")}
        print()
        p += 1
    }
}
// If you use UnsafePointer<CChar>, this can be simplified.
extension String {
    init?(sjisptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) {
        self.init(cString: UnsafeRawPointer(sjisptr).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self), encoding: .shiftJIS)
    }
}
// create string from UTF-16 with terminating U+0000
extension String {
    init?(utf16ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) {
        var len = 0
        while (utf16ptr[len] != 0) { //Detecting U+0000 as a terminator.
            len += 1
        }
        let data = Data(bytes: utf16ptr, count: len * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)
        self.init(data: data, encoding: .utf16LittleEndian)
    }
}
func test() {
    let str = "helloはろー"

    // (A) utf-8
    let utf8 = str.cString(using: .utf8)!
    dumpmem(0, utf8)
    let str1 = String(cString: utf8)
    print(str1)  // helloはろー

    // (B) shift-JIS
    let sjis = str.cString(using: .shiftJIS)!
    sjis.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        let uint8p = UnsafeRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        dumpmem(0, uint8p)
        let str2 = String(sjisptr: uint8p)!
        print(str2)  // helloはろー
    }

    // (C) utf-16 ==> to create a byte representation of UTF-16 terminated with U+0000
    var utf16 = str.data(using: .utf16LittleEndian)!
    utf16.append(contentsOf: [0,0]) //Append U+0000 as terminator.
    utf16.withUnsafeBytes {(uint16p: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) in
        dumpmem(utf16.count, uint16p)
        let str3 = String(utf16ptr: uint16p)!
        print(str3)
    }

    // (D) utf-16
    let u16s = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.allocate(capacity: str.utf16.count + 1) //<- `cnt * 4` is not appropriate
    var len = 0
    for code in str.utf16 {
        u16s[len] = code
        len += 1
    }
    u16s[len] = 0 //Append U+0000 as terminator.
    dumpmem((len+1) * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size, u16s)
    let str4 = String(utf16ptr: u16s)!
    u16s.deallocate(capacity: str.utf16.count + 1)
    print(str4)  // helloはろー
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow has some "localized" family sites for "日本語", "español", "Português" or "русско". If you prefer "日本語" (guessed by "はろー"), try visiting [スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/).